# Standard deviation of combinations of dices

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, stdev

I am trying to find stdev for a sequence of numbers that were extracted from combinations of dice (30) that sum up to 120. I am very new to Python, so this code makes the console freeze because the numbers are endless and I am not sure how to fit them all into a smaller, more efficient function. What I did is:

- found all possible combinations of 30 dice;
- filtered combinations that sum up to 120;
- multiplied all items in the list within result list;
- tried extracting standard deviation.

Here is the code:

```
import itertools
import numpy

dice = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
subset = itertools.product(dice, repeat = 30)

result = []
for x in subset:
    if sum(x) == 120:
        result.append(x)

my_result = numpy.product(result, axis = 1).tolist()
std = numpy.std(my_result)

print(std)
```

Comment: Have you tried this with smaller numbers?  I get a noticeable drop in speed for even 10 dice.  A minor point - you don't need `tolist`, at least not to do `std`.

Comment: you are going to have `6**30 = 221073919720733357899776` combinations, so please be patient... ;)

Comment: It's been an hour - I am loosing hope at this point :( 
that's a disturbingly long number, I agree @MaxU

Comment: If you would run your program on [the fastest supercomputer in the world - Sunway TaihuLight (93 PetaFLOPS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunway_TaihuLight) it would take longer than: `221073919720733357899776/(93*10**15)/60/60/24 = 27.51` hours, because you are going to do multiple operations...

Comment: that's reassuring! :) @MaxU

Comment: I don't think you can solve this problem in a brute-force way, try an analytic approach!

Answer (score 1):

Note that `D(X^2) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2`, you can solve this problem analytically by following equations.

```
f[i][N] = sum(k*f[i-1][N-k])        (1<=k<=6)
g[i][N] = sum(k^2*g[i-1][N-k])
h[i][N] = sum(h[i-1][N-k])

f[1][k] = k ( 1<=k<=6)
g[1][k] = k^2 ( 1<=k<=6)
h[1][k] = 1 ( 1<=k<=6)
```

Sample implementation:

```
import numpy as np

Nmax = 120
nmax = 30
min_value = 1
max_value = 6
f = np.zeros((nmax+1, Nmax+1), dtype ='object')
g = np.zeros((nmax+1, Nmax+1), dtype ='object') # the intermediate results will be really huge, to keep them accurate we have to utilize python big-int
h = np.zeros((nmax+1, Nmax+1), dtype ='object')
for i in range(min_value, max_value+1):
    f[1][i] = i
    g[1][i] = i**2
    h[1][i] = 1

for i in range(2, nmax+1):
    for N in range(1, Nmax+1):
        f[i][N] = 0
        g[i][N] = 0
        h[i][N] = 0
        for k in range(min_value, max_value+1):
            f[i][N] += k*f[i-1][N-k]
            g[i][N] += (k**2)*g[i-1][N-k]
            h[i][N] += h[i-1][N-k]

result = np.sqrt(float(g[nmax][Nmax]) / h[nmax][Nmax] - (float(f[nmax][Nmax]) / h[nmax][Nmax]) ** 2)
# result = 32128174994365296.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You ask for a result of an unfiltered lengths of 6<sup>30</sup> = 2*10<sup>23</sup>, impossible to handle as such.

There are two possibilities that can be combined:

1. Include more thinking to pre-treat the problem, e.g. on how to sample only
   those with sum 120.
2. Do a Monte Carlo simulation instead, i.e. don't sample all
   combinations, but only a random couple of 1000 to obtain a representative
   sample to determine std sufficiently accurate.

Now, I only apply (2), giving the brute force code:

```
N = 30 # number of dices
M = 100000 # number of samples
S = 120 # required sum

result = [[random.randint(1,6) for _ in xrange(N)] for _ in xrange(M)]
result = [s for s in result if sum(s) == S]
```

Now, that result should be comparable to your result before using `numpy.product` ... that part I couldn't follow, though...

Ok, if you are out after the standard deviation of the product of the 30 dices, that is what your code does. Then I need 1 000 000 samples to get roughly reproducible values for std (1 digit) - takes my PC about 20 seconds, still considerably less than 1 million years :-D.

Is a number like 3.22*10<sup>16</sup> what you are looking for?

**Edit after comments:**
Well, sampling the frequency of numbers instead gives only 6 independent variables - even 4 actually, by substituting in the constraints (sum = 120, total number = 30). My current code looks like this:

```
def p2(b, s):
    return 2**b * 3**s[0] * 4**s[1] * 5**s[2] * 6**s[3]

hits = range(31)
subset = itertools.product(hits, repeat=4) # only 3,4,5,6 frequencies
product = []
permutations = []
for s in subset:
    b = 90 - (2*s[0] + 3*s[1] + 4*s[2] + 5*s[3]) # 2 frequency
    a = 30 - (b + sum(s)) # 1 frequency
    if 0 <= b <= 30 and 0 <= a <= 30:
        product.append(p2(b, s))
        permutations.append(1) # TODO: Replace 1 with possible permutations
print numpy.std(product)  # TODO: calculate std manually, considering permutations
```

This computes in about 1 second, but the confusing part is that I get as a result 1.28737023733e+17. Either my previous approaches or this one has a bug - or both.

**Sorry - not that easy:** The sampling is not of the same probability - that is the problem here. Each sample has a different number of possible combinations, giving its weight, which has to be considered before taking the std-deviation. I have drafted that in the code above.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Dr.V 
unfortunately, I need an exact standard deviation, so the sample size won't help in this case.. :(

Comment: Well, I am inclined to ask "Why?" Is it an academic exercise? Then I suspect the expected solution is more analytic. As an improvement to above, I could only offer a Monte Carlo Markov Chain (MCMC) method, giving 2-3 digits with one minute calculation time, still about 3.22e16. I would be thrilled to see an analytic (exact) solution. ... Wait a minute ... Maybe try to represent the sample not as a 30-size tuple, but as a 6-size tuple, describing how many 1,2,3,4,5,6 are in the sample.

Comment: I thought about it too, but not sure how to calculate all permutations for each tuple..